# How can I update the id of items?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I don't know if I need to create a new array for the ID. I don't how `ListView` normally works with an array.

When I delete an item, the problem is that the other items are kept with the previous ID they had.

I want to add an ID on the left side of the items:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String>arrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;


    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);


    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final int which_item = position;

            new AlertDialog.Builder( Menu.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                    .setTitle("¿Estás seguro?")
                    .setMessage("¿Estás seguro de que quiere eliminar este objeto?")
                    .setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            arrayList.remove(which_item);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", null)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = arrayList.size()+1;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.add_icon:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Adiciones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.add_identificacion:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Identificación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
            arrayList.add(id + " : Identificación" );
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```